# Loop through table and display as Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I need to get some data out of a table and into a google chart but am getting lost as to how to loop through it correctly

HTML

```
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Result</th>
</tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="date">24/12/2012</td>
        <td class="score">51</td>
        <td class="result">30<span class="over"></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="date">28/12/2012</td>
        <td class="score">52</td>
        <td class="result">31<span class="over"></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="date">02/12/2012</td>
        <td class="score">44</td>
        <td class="result">19<span class="over"></span></td>
    </tr>
```

Here's the google chart javascript

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Score', 'Result'],
      [date,  score,      result],
    ]);
```

I'm guessing I need something like this...

```
  var date = $this.find(".date").html();
  var score = $this.find(".score").html();
  var result = $this.find(".result").html();
```

Comment: That should mostly work if `$this` refers to the table row you are pulling data from.  Pulling data from `.result` will be a bit trickier, as you need to capture the number without the `<span>`.  You will also want to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` on the numbers as appropriate (as they will otherwise be interpreted as strings).

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Date');
data.addColumn('number','Score');
data.addColumn('number','Result');

$('table tr').not(':first').each(function(i,tr) {
   data.addRow([
      $(tr).find('.date').text(),
      parseInt($(tr).find('.score').text()),
      parseInt($(tr).find('.result').text())
   ]);
});
```

We know the column names, so they can be hardcoded. The data is extracted in the loop. Column data is found by class-name, but you could use index as well. Note `parseInt` to ensure that it actually *is* numbers being inserted.

[image]

However, it could be more generalistic and reuseable if you had a correct formed table structure like

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```